# ipython line number out of order creates NameError

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have an ipython notebook running in my browser, and I have a NameError for 'x', in which it's defined just above in the notebook, but has a numerically lower line number, which I believe is the reason for the NameError.

For example, it looks like this:

```
In [12]: x = np.random.random((3, 4))
In [4]: print x

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-73c1d467e5a9> in <module>()
      1 #your code here
----> 2 print x

NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

How do I fix the execution order here?

Comment: The number tells you the execution number of each block. In your exemple, if you run [12] then [4], the [4] will become [13] and print x. It seems like you try to print x before defining it.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that's what was happening. Can't do anything with a variable that hasn't been defined yet. How does one change the execution order in ipython? I assumed it was top to bottom, which in practice here has proved false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of the left simply indicates the order of execution of block of codes.

Depending on how you run each cell the number changes. In the example, you simply need to run [12] then [4] which will change to [13]. And x will print.

The order is up to you. However, on the top bar you can click on Run All, which will run all the blocks top-down.

To avoid confusion and variables already defined. I suggest to regularly restart the IPython kernel (top bar also) and then run all.

Comment: Ok, that's just unexpected behavior I'll begin to learn. Your advice to restart the kernel and then run all was just what I needed. Thank you.